# SharePoint 2010: Is it possible to declare list relations without having list instances?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

First of all I have to excuse for the maybe misleading question: I read that it's not possible, so the question actually is: Is this true and if yes, is there another possibility to accomplish this relation-behavior? But let's describe my situation:

I'm developing a small SharePoint 2010 solution and am not sure how to deploy some relations. I want to deploy everything with only the help of packages and features, that means I cannot use the SharePoint UI.  That's what I want to do:

I'm designing several content types, e.g. *Report* and *Entry*. I'm using XML-Definitions to design them. Then I build list definitions that describe that e.g. the *ReportList* handles items of the type *Report*. And now I'm stuck: I want to declare that every *Entry* belongs to one *Report*. Therefore I'm adding a lookup field to the definition of the content type for *Entry*, but lookup fields need list instances when I deploy their content types.

I would like to declare the relation without a need of these instances. Users should have the ability to decide which lists they want to add for themselves. Is there a best practice for declaring such relation without having list instances?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow the following article. It will be a help for you creating lookup columns with list. Definition is possible as it is used in the blog site. [Lookup Sitecolumn](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2007/04/creating-list-based-site-columns-as.html).

Comment: Thank you, I was following the suggestions of the article and realized a suitable solution. Although I'm not really happy with the procedure to manually add relations in a feature receiver, it seems to be the only solution.